# Passing variable inside query using python

Tags: python, sql

I am using below code to upload file from local machine into SQL server. Currently, code correctly picks the file from `hardcoded location` and stores into DB.

How to pass variable name instead of hardcoded location:`C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ExcelFile_7964.xlsx`?

When I replaced the location with `?` and pass it into query it does not works.

Code:

```
Query = '''
    DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);
    SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ExcelFile_7964.xlsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Doc;
    INSERT INTO[TEST].[dbo].[TABLE]([file_type_id], [file], [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_required])
    VALUES(?,@Document, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        '''
values = (file_type_id, file_name, filing_id, created_at, created_by, is_required)

connsql.cursor().execute(Query, values)
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a more elegant solution.

```
Query = '''
    DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);
    SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '%s', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Doc;
    INSERT INTO[TEST].[dbo].[TABLE]([file_type_id], [file], [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_required])
    VALUES(?,@Document, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ''' % sanitized_escaped_filename
```

This solution risks of course SQL injection if you do not perform proper sanitizing and sql escaping of your filename.

Depending on your context this might be an issue to be adressed or not.

It all depends who is writing the SQL code an dwho provides the file name.

If the file name is for example comming from a web interface you definitely must sanitize and escape